# Can the OP accept an answer when the question is already on hold?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, on-hold

This should be an easy one, yet all searches point to "Can you *answer* a question which is on hold?" or the like.

Comment: ProgramFOX's answer is confirmed by previous discussions on the global Meta: [Can an answer of a closed question be accepted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/91827), [Is allowing voting and accepting answers on closed questions best practice?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24845), [Should people be able to accept answers after the question has been closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96299), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I once posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19141302/2619912), and the OP accepted it after the question was put on hold.

Comment: OK, cool, unless it fell into a grace period.. (In any case one of those cases, which make shake my head - Too broad to be answered or too many possibilities..?)

Comment: Probably the question was closed as "too broad" because it also was not very clear and might have sounded like "I'm looking for a regex cheat sheet".

Comment: Yeah. I call it the Nomad syndrome   ;-)